# How do we get around the Lotus Notes 60 Gb database barrier

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Are there ways to get around the upper database size limit on Notes databases?  We are compacting a database that is still approaching 60 gigs in size.  Thank you very much if you can offer a suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you could find a way to get over the 64GB limit it would not be the recommended solution. Splitting up the application into multiple databases is far better if you wish to improve performance and retain the stability of your Domino server. If you think you have to have everything in the same database in order to be able to search, please look up domain search and multi-database search in the Domino Administrator help.

- Maybe some parts of the data is "old" and could be put into one or more archive databases instead?
- Maybe you have a lot of large attachments and can store them in a series of attachment databases?
- Maybe you have a lot of complicated views that can be streamlined or eliminated and thereby save a lot of space and keep everything in the same database for the time being? (Remove sorting on columns where not needed, using "click on column header to sort" is a sure way to increase the size of the view index.)

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming your database is large because of file attachments as well. In that case look into DAOS - it will store all file attachments on filesystem (server functionality - transparent to clients and existing applications).

As a bonus it finds duplicates and stores them only once.

More here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-green/

Answer (score 3):

Just a stab in the dark:

Use the DB2 storage method instead of to a Domino server?

Comment: You can use DB2 to store the notes database instead of the domino server, but the code of the Notes app stays the same.

Comment: I looked like a great idea at the time (ca. 2006 ?), but has anybody built a production system on that ?

Comment: Long since stopped using Domino.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that 80-90% of that space is taken up by file attachments.  My suggestion is to move all the attachments to a file share, provided everyone can access that share, or to an FTP server that everyone can connect to.

It's not ideal because security becomes an issue - now you need to manage credentials to the Notes database AND to the external file share - however it'll be worth the effort from a Notes administrator's perspective.

In the Notes documents, just provide a link to the file.  If users are adding these files via a Notes form, perhaps you can add some background code to extract the file from the document after it has been saved, and replace it with a link to that file.

Answer (score 3):

The 64GB is not actually an absolute limit, you can go above that, I've seen 80GB and even close to 100Gb although once your past 64Gb you can get problems at any time. The limit is not actually Notes, its the underlying file system, I've seen this on AS400 but the great thing about Notes is that if you do get a huge crash you can still access all the documents and pull everything out to new copies using scheduled agents even if you can no longer get views to open in the client.

Your best best is regular archiving, if it is file attachments then anything over two years old doesn't need to be in main system, just brief synopsis and link, you could even have 5 year archive, 2 year archive 1 year archive etc, data will continue to accumulate and has to be managed, irrespective of what platform you use to store it.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue really is large file attachments, I would certainly recommend looking into implementing DAOS on your server / database. It is only available with Domino Server 8.5 and later. On the other hand, if your database contains over 100,000+ documents, you may want to look seriously at dividing the data into multiple NSF's - at that number of documents, you need to be very careful about your view design, your lookup code, etc.

Some documented successes with DAOS:
http://www.edbrill.com/ebrill/edbrill.nsf/dx/yet-another-daos-success-story-from-darren-duke?opendocument&comments

Answer (score 1):

If you're database is getting to 60gb.. don't use a Domino solution you need to switch to a relational database. You need to archive or move documents across several databases. Although you can get to 60gb, you shouldn't do it. The performance hit for active databases is significant. Not so much a problem for static databases.

Comment: How does using an RDBMS help when the original system is not relational?

Answer (score 1):

I would also look at removing any unnecessary views & their indexes. View indexes can occupy 80-90% of your disk space. If you can't remove them, simplify their sorting arrangements/formulas and remove any unnecessary column sorting options. I halved a 50gb down to 25gb with a few simple changes like this and virtually no users noticed.

Answer (score 1):

One path could be, for once, to start with the user. Do all the users need to access all that data all the time ? If no, it's time to split or archive. If yes, there is probably a flaw in the design of the application.

Technically, I would add to the previous comments a suggestion to check the [many options for compaction](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21084388). Quick and dirty : disard all view indices, but be sure to rebuild at least the one for the default view if you don't want your users to riot. See [updall](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/admn_updalloptions_r.html)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to check: make sure you have checked

> [x] Use LZ1 compression for attachments

in db properties.